# How do I create a static timestamp (date) function in google sheets based on the answer I provided in a previous cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

[Here is a picture of what my spreadsheet looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ei66s.png)
I have certain data in columns A-G that are not relevant for this question but include things like shipment details, clients, etc.

I would like column I to automatically input the current date, based on the answer in column H. So when I click "yes" I would like an automatic STATIC date (MM-dd-YYYY) to show up in I. For example, if I click yes today, April 29th 2022, when I return to the spreadsheet tomorrow, the date will still read April 29th 2022 and not update to April 30th, 2022.

I have tried multiple scripts as well as if functions, and I am having difficulty finding one that actually works. My biggest challenge has been that the date automatically refreshes the next day, or that the script simply does not work and no date is entered into the corresponding cell.

An additional note - half of my spreadsheet already has dates in the column that were manually entered. The script or formula or combination of both that I use needs to not overwrite the data that are already there.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you perhaps include the screenshot of the spreadsheet in the question itself? The link might break with time.

Answer (score 0):

#### Generate Date

```
function onEdit(e) {
  sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()== "Enter Sheet Name" && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.value == "yes") {
    e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"MM-dd-yyyy"))
  }
}
```